# Can you define a variable using vars: halfway through an ansible script

Tags: syntax, ansible

I am trying to create an ansible script that will ask the user for the address/domain names of there NTP servers, and then save them to a list.

```
---

- name: Chrony Service Setup
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ntpServers: []
  tasks:

    - name: "Ask user if they wish to add there own NTP servers"
      pause:
        prompt: "Do you want to add unique NTP server (y/n)?"
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        addNTP: "{{ result.user_input }}"

    - block:

      - name:
        debug:
          msg: "Hello"

      vars:
        ntpServer: "initVal"

      - block:

        - name:
          debug:
            msg: "Hello 2"

        when: ntpServer != ""


      when: addNTP == "y"
```

Currently the script should just print out "Hello 2" constantly, as the when in that block is never satisfied.

I actually get this error:

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key
...

On line 25 -block:
```

I am pretty new to ansible so I was wondering if you can't define variables halfway through a script.

Any help apprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put it in the middle of a list like that; like `when:` the `vars:` is part of the overall dict, not part of the list under `block:`.

On a style note, I find it much more readable to put keys like `when` before `block`, not after; it requires much less visual matching of indentation levels and makes the logic easier to follow.

```
- name: Chrony Service Setup
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ntpServers: []
    addNTP: "{{ result.user_input }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Prompt for NTP server
      pause:
        prompt: "Do you want to add unique NTP server (y/n)?"
      register: result

    - when: addNTP == "y"
      vars:
        ntpServer: initVal
      block:
        - name:
          debug:
            msg: "Hello"

        - when: ntpServer != ""
          block:
            - name:
              debug:
                msg: "Hello 2"
```